# Email send to 2 different locations in php

Tags: php, forms, email

So, if you fill out this contact form i've got. Then, you'll fill out your return email just like every contact form out there. This variable is set to

```
 $from=$_POST["email"];
```

So, I have a new feature in my contact form that enables users to send a copy of it to their email address that they submitted in the "email" section of the form. Except, I have this php code to take care of this for that user if they checked the box saying yes they wanted to...

```
if ($_POST['copy'] == "on") {
     $receiver = "my email addr" || $from;
 }
```

with the name "copy" being the checkbox, here is that code now...

```
<div class="6u 12u$(small)">
    <input type="checkbox" id="copy" name="copy">
    <label for="copy">Email me a copy of this message</label>
</div>
```

Now, idk if this is the problem, but when I submitted the form with "get" then checked the box for the copy then it came back in the url bar as "&copy=on".

Comment: Why is that a problem and where is the question?

Answer (score 2):

this is not valid

```
  $receiver = "my email addr" || $from;
```

to send to another address you append with a comma

```
  $receiver = "my email addr".','.$from;
```

then:

```
mail($receiver,$subject,$body);
```